# How to refresh a Bokeh JInja2-based app

Tags: python, jinja2, bokeh

I have a simple bokeh application that creates a plot and insert it into a Jinja template.

```
import io
from jinja2 import Template
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import INLINE
from bokeh.util.browser import view

template = Template("""
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bokeh with Jinja example</title>
    {{ js_resources }}
    {{ css_resources }}
    {{ script }}
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a test</h1>
{{ myplot['myplot'] }}
</body>
</html>
""")

# The plot
TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
y1 = [0, 8, 2, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 25, 28, 4, 7]
xr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
yr1 = Range1d(start=0, end=30)
p1 = figure(x_range=xr1, y_range=yr1, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=300,     plot_height=300)
p1.scatter(x1, y1, size=12, color="red", alpha=0.5)


js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
css_resources = INLINE.render_css()

plots = {'myplot': p1}
script, div = components(plots)

print div.keys()

html = template.render(js_resources=js_resources,
                       css_resources=css_resources,
                       script=script,
                       myplot=div)

filename = 'embed_multiple.html'

with io.open(filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(html)

view(filename)
```

The question is: I need to periodically (es.: every 5 seconds) re-read datas (x1) and re-plot the chart to display the update graph.

How can I do that? I read about streams but I wasn't able to implement them with a Jinja template.

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Se at bokeh server applications: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html

Comment: Unfortunately I have problems following that tutorial and matching template based docs with auto refresh...